# google app script с регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Не получается заставить работать google app script с регулярным выражением `\[[^\[]+\]`

```
function kvaskob(a) {
  var regexp = new RegExp("\[[^\[]+\]");
  var newstr = a.match(regexp);
  return(newstr[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте экранировать слеши:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("\\[[^\\[]+\\]")
```